# SQL Server won't let me use a column of a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Picture may be better than explanation :

[image]

As you can see, SQL Server won't let me pick the "sensor_id" for my trigger. i always have "invalid column name" as error. How can i fix it ?

## EDIT

Here is my wiew query :

```
SELECT        c.id_capteur AS sensor_id, sr.alias, c.virtual, MAX(d.date) AS date, d.value
FROM            dbo.Smartparking_reference AS sr INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Sensor AS c ON c.id_capteur = sr.id_capteur LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Sensor_data AS d ON c.id_capteur = d.id_capteur
GROUP BY sr.alias, c.id_capteur, d.id_capteur, c.virtual, d.value
```

Comment: `inserted` is a reserved table name so are you actually inserting the "sensor_id" column in a table anywhere so it gets picked up?

Comment: Can you show the entire trigger definition?

Comment: Can you please share the design of `inserted` table? Here the confusion is like, you are using `inserted` in your query to use `sensor_id` column but after checking in left side, i think view name is `ParkingSlot`.

Comment: Is the "error" just InteliSense? Can you ignore the it and run the script to create the trigger?

Comment: Try `alt, e, i, r` to refresh intellisense. menu: edit > intellisense > refresh.

Comment: You are forgetting that you can insert more than one row at a time, if you insert two or more rows `select @sensor = i.sensor_id FROM inserted i` is going to be non deterministic, and only do anything for one of the rows inserted. You should **always** write triggers based on the assumption that the memory-resident table `inserted` will contain multiple rows.

Comment: What @GarethD said is extremely important. No trigger should ever set a value of a field in inserted to a scalar variable. That is an extremely bad technique leading to data integrity issues. The problem is that it will run but you may not notice for months that all the records that should have had action from the trigger did not. Even if you think you will ever only insert one record, over time people need to run scripts and imports and other things besides the application insert.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Sensor_id is the IDENTITY column of the table, so it doesn't get "inserted" by an insert statement, and therefore its value isn't in the `inserted` table.

Comment: The identity column and value should be in the `inserted` virtual table.

Comment: I will specifiy my view query